# Se pide que el usuario escriba un numero y si ese numero está en el diccionario, tiene que aparecer su información. Tengo esto hecho pero no me sale

Tags: python-3.x

```
#In the execution of the script, the user is
```

asked to input an employee ID. If the employee exists in the dictionary, his or her information is
displayed on-screen. Otherwise, a message stating the circumstance is shown.

```
translationTable={1233:['Jay Gatsby',1972,45600], \
  536:['Molly Bloom',1984,26100], \
  4468:['Atticus Finch',1968,33000], \
  3365:['Sam Spade',1988,18000], \
  7321:['Quentin Compson',1977,68000], \
  897:['Dean Moriarty',1980,36400]}

employeeID=int(input('Please input the ID of the employee: ')

if employeeID in translationTable :
   employeeData=translationTable[employeeID]
   print('The employee name is: ', translationTable[1])
   print('The employee year of birth is: ', translationTable[2])
   print('The employee salary is: ', translationTable[3])

else:
   print('The employee could not be found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente código

```
translationTable={1233:['Jay Gatsby',1972,45600], \
  536:['Molly Bloom',1984,26100], \
  4468:['Atticus Finch',1968,33000], \
  3365:['Sam Spade',1988,18000], \
  7321:['Quentin Compson',1977,68000], \
  897:['Dean Moriarty',1980,36400]}
ID = int(input('ingresar código: '))

if ID in translationTable:
    print("Name: " + str(translationTable[ID][0]))
    print("year of birth: " + str(translationTable[ID][1]))
    print("salary is: " + str(translationTable[ID][2]))
else:
    print("No existe")
```

El problema que tiene tu código es que falta el indice translationTable[Falta indice][atributo]:

Saludos

Comment: @Leire comenta si te funcionó el código. Saludos

Comment: En la respuesta esta el motivo por el cual no funciona, saludos

Comment: Ahora si que funciona, muchas gracias!!!!!